# Yii2 Progress Widget Clickable Fields

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to make my page display a number of different progress widgets together to form a dynamic bigger progress bar. Each one of the widgets needs to be clickable to take the user to that respective stage. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<?php
    $retVal = "";
    $stages = Phases::find()->asArray()->all();
    foreach($stages as $stage)
    {
        $percent = PrjApprovals::percentageComplete($model->id, $stage['phase']);
        echo $retVal = '<div style="float:left; padding-top: 20px;">' .
        Progress::widget
        ([
            'percent' => $percent,
            'label' => $stage['phase'],
            'attributes' => 
                function($model)
                {
                    $url = Url::to(['phases/' . $stage['phase'], 'id' => $model->id]);
                    return ['onclick' => "window.location.href='{$url}'"];
                },
         ]) . '</div>';
    }
?>
```

I need the link to not change any of the content in the progress widget but make it so that the current content is clickable. The link needs to send the user to whichever stage they clicked on and with that respective model id ($model->id).

I know "attributes" is not right, I've tried barOptions, options, rowOptions and everything else I can find. Still no luck.

Comment: Do you want to have the stacked progress bar? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked

Comment: No, there's no need. All I'm hoping for is that each one of the progress widgets can send the user to a different stage with the same model id in the GET request. The link should look like /Controller/Action + id=$model->id.
For example: /basic/web/index.php?r=phases%2Finitiation&id=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options`  attribute .. can contain all the html key for a tag .. so you can use class , id  ... and href too .. and obviuosly onclick to .. but accept an array (with model value)  and not (i think)  an anonymous function, so you should form your option value content in your model  ..

```
<?php
$retVal = "";
$stages = Phases::find()->asArray()->all();
foreach($stages as $stage)
{
    $percent = PrjApprovals::percentageComplete($model->id, $stage['phase']);
    echo $retVal = '<div style="float:left; padding-top: 20px;">' .
    Progress::widget
    ([
        'percent' => $percent,
        'label' => $stage['phase'],
        'options' => ['href' => 'your_url'], 
     ]) 
}
?>
```

or if you have a model attribute mystage_link you can use

```
     'options' => ['href' =>$model->mystage_link],
```

Comment: How do I add the 'id' as a GET and the stage to the url? I've tried this:
'options' => ['href' => '/phases/' . $stage['phase'], 'id' => $model->id],
But no dice.

Comment: Each stage has to be dynamically added to the URL as does the model id.

Comment: @jamesdoe   well seems my answer  lead you to the proper solution .. should be fair  you rate it properly..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

$url = Url::to(['phases/' . $gate, 'id' => $model['id']]);

'options' => ['onclick' => "window.location.href='{$url}'"],

Thank you everyone!